# How to fix java File download exception?

Tags: java, download, outputstream

This is a short piece of code to download a file in browser.I had this piece of code working before but now its throwing an exception. The exception comes during while loop parsing and I am not able to find any solution for this. I believe that this code is not the problem but I am unable to find what is causing this. To clearify the file is there with data and no errors.

```
    File newFile = new File("resources\\report.xlsx");
            FileInputStream fileIn;

            try {
            fileIn = new FileInputStream(newFile);

            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

                byte[] outputByte = new byte[1024];
            int byteContent;

            while ((byteContent = fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, 1024)) != -1) 
                    {
            out.write(outputByte, 0, byteContent);
            }
                fileIn.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And it throws this exception.

```
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
    durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:341)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:766)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:671)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:376)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:354)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
        at com.siemens.controller.AjaxController.readFile(AjaxController.java:91)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
    durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:105)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:144)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1223)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:513)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:451)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:530)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:189)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:599)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:329)
        ... 45 more
```

Comment: Translation please.

Comment: There is little information here to help you out. My best guess is that there are wrong http headers (for example the content-type or content length), so the client aborts the connection because is receiving a response not consistent with the request.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your codes. The error message is in German and it says it all:

```
Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert
    durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen
```

The connection to the host computer is broken (disconnected). Check the connection to your (host) server before you start to write.